# grpc-swift: How to set timeout for an RPC in Swift?

Tags: grpc, grpc-swift

I am using https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift for inter-process communication.  I have a GRPC server written in Go that listens on a unix domain socket, and a macOS app written in Swift that communicates with it over the socket.

Let's say the Go server process is not running and I make an RPC call from my Swift program.  The default timeout before the call will fail is 20 seconds, but I would like to shorten it to 1 second.  I am trying to do something like this:

```swift
let callOptions = CallOptions(timeLimit: .seconds(1)) // <-- Does not compile
```

This fails with compile error Type `'TimeLimit' has no member 'seconds'`.

What is the correct way to decrease the timeout interval for Swift GRPC calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the error `TimeLimit` don't have a member `seconds`. This `seconds` function that you are trying to access is inside `TimeAmount`. So if you want to use a deadline, you will need to use:

```swift
CallOptions(timeLimit: .deadline(.now() + .seconds(1)))
```

here the `.now` is inside `NIODeadline` and it as a `+` operator defined for adding with `TimeLimit` (check [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/blob/94969e72808574b7d1b89fddff5f658258fda548/Sources/NIOCore/EventLoop.swift#L624)).

and for a timeout:

```swift
CallOptions(timeLimit: .timeout(.seconds(1)))
```

Note that I'm not an expert in Swift, but I checked in [TimeLimitTests.swift](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-swift/blob/c88f038cdee150543ffcbb44a987db58abaf4d9c/Tests/GRPCTests/TimeLimitTests.swift) and that seems to be the idea.

Comment: This leads to a compile error also:  "Type 'NIODeadline' has no member 'seconds'"

Comment: But the tests link in your post helped me find a solution!  `CallOptions(timeLimit: TimeLimit.timeout(.seconds(1)))` compiles and has the desired behavior.  If you update your answer to this, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Note: Timeout and Deadline are different concepts, I recommend you to check the one that is best for your use case